# alsamixer / amixer supported usb audio class 2 controls

Tags: usb, audio, alsa, usb-audio, alsamixer

I am currently developing a usb soundcard that is usb audio class 2 compliant.
In my current setup I have audio and mute controls for several channels working in alsamixer.

The USB audio class 2 spec also supports a lot of other controls such as bass, mid, treble, equalizers, effects, etc. I have been trying to find a list of controls supported by alsamixer but the documentation does not mention any specifics on what kind of controls are supported.

If someone has a list with supported controls or an alternative command-line program that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such

> *list of supported controls*

since… whatever [*control element*](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/control.html) appropriately exposed by the device can be taken into account by `amixer`, v.g listed by the `amixer scontrols` command and accessible on the graphical interface via some button, slider or list according to its type (BOOLEAN, INTEGER or ENUM respectively) by calling [alsalib's snd_ctl* functions](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___control.html#ga952c52ef86124847f9bf12ee3dbfa5a3).
These control elements can get different sort of properties (min/max values, step size, list of possible values)
From amixer's side, there is absolutely nothing specific to usb audio class 2 devices.

These *control elements* are defined by the [driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/sound/kernel-api/writing-an-alsa-driver.html#control-interface) in `struct snd_ctl_elem_info` objects of the like

```
static int snd_myctl_mono_info(struct snd_kcontrol *kcontrol, struct snd_ctl_elem_info *uinfo)
{
        uinfo->type = SNDRV_CTL_ELEM_TYPE_BOOLEAN;
        uinfo->count = 1;
        uinfo->value.integer.min = 0;
        uinfo->value.integer.max = 1;
        return 0;
}
```

for what would be a boolean *control element*.
Cf hereabove link for more details on *control elements* as well as the [ALSA Kernel API Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/sound/kernel-api/index.html) for official documentation and detailed examples of sound drivers code.

Some alsa drivers can help by pre-defining (v.g. not restricting to some exhaustive list) some controls, for what concerns the [usb_audio driver](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/sound/usb/usbmixer.c#L132) specifically :

```
enum {
    USB_FEATURE_NONE = 0,
    USB_FEATURE_MUTE = 1,
    USB_FEATURE_VOLUME,
    USB_FEATURE_BASS,
    USB_FEATURE_MID,
    USB_FEATURE_TREBLE,
    USB_FEATURE_GEQ,
    USB_FEATURE_AGC,
    USB_FEATURE_DELAY,
    USB_FEATURE_BASSBOOST,
    USB_FEATURE_LOUDNESS
};
```

Comment: Thx, the usb driver code also definitely helps.